# Counting Cars on a highway

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Upon exiting a certain highway, cars turn either left or right,
>   independently of one another, with probability 0.3 to turn left.
>   Knowing that at least 2 of the last 15 cars that exited the highway
>   turned left, what is the probability that no more than 2 cars actually
>   turned left?

I used the binomial distribution 15C2 * 0.3^2 * 0.7^13 and got 0.0915.
I mean that's close to the actual answer (0.095) but I'm pretty sure I made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly $2$ cars turn left with probability $\binom{15}2(0.3)^2(0.7)^{13}=0.09156$, and less than $2$ turn left with probability $\binom{15}1(0.3)^1(0.7)^{14}+\binom{15}0(0.3)^0(0.7)^{15}=0.03527$. Thus the required probability is a conditional one, given by
$$\frac{0.09156}{1-0.03527}=0.0949$$

Comment: So I divide by this number to cancel the probability of having less than 2?

Comment: @O.Sinno Rather, you are conditioning on the fact that at least two cars turned left.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider only $1$ car turned left and only $0$ car turned left cases.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_i$ the event "**there are exactly i turns to left**

In order to answer your question, you must count the number of forms you got exactly 2 turns to left from 13 cars: $\#A_2={13 \choose 2}=\dfrac{13!}{2!\,11!}=\dfrac{13.12}{2}=78$ and the universe are the forms you got at least 2 turns to left: $\sum\limits_{i=2}^{13}\#A_i=\sum\limits_{i=2}^{13}{13 \choose i}$

Trick $2^{13}=(1+1)^{13}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{13}{13 \choose i}\rightarrow \sum\limits_{i=2}^{13}{13 \choose i} = 2^{13} -{13 \choose 0}-{13 \choose 1}=2^{13}-1-13=8178$

Then, your probability is $\dfrac{78}{8178}=\dfrac{13}{1363}$

Comment: 0.9537784299339692‬